# How to query specific relation(s) in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, relation

I have database tables structured like this (It is something like international conference proceedings):

```
languages (id, abbr)

papers (id, title, fulltext, language_id)

keywords (id)
keyword_translations (id, label, keyword_id, language_id) // cointains language-specific tranlation of given keyword
paper_keywords (id, paper_id, keyword_id) //M:N relation between papers and keywords

usage (id)
usage_translations (id, label, usage_id, language_id)
paper_usage (id, paper_id, usage_id) //M:N relation between papers and usages
```

This describes papers and their metadata. The desired UI should be in multiple languages, therefore there are "translation tables".

In my Eloquent models I have built all simple M:N `belonsToMany` relations like "all papers with this equipment". The models look like this:

```
class Paper extends Model
{
    public function keywords()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Keyword', 'paper_keyword');
    }

    public function usages()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Usage', 'paper_usage');
    }
}
```

```
class Keyword extends Model
{
    public function translations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\KeywordTranslation');
    }

    public function papers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Paper', 'paper_keyword');
    }
}
```

…and the same for usage.

Now I need to query a specific paper given by its ID (or maybe multiple papers) and all keywords and usage belonging to it - but those only with a given language_id.
*(This language_id concerns only the translations (for the UI), the paper can have different language_id. A typical example is that I want to see a Slovak or Polish paper, but the UI is in Czech, so there should be Czech labels for the keywords and other metadata).*

I know I can do `App\Paper::with(['usages.translations', 'keywords.translations'])->find(1605);` but that would bring all translations, not just the language-specific. In plain SQL I would simply join all the tables using some aliases and query `WHERE keyword_translations.language_id = 1`, but in Eloquent?

I would like to avoid solutions requiring database modification.

Comment: Are you looking for a `where()`  with `orWhere()` clause?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need below query

```
$languageId = 'language_id';

$papers = App\Paper::with(['usages.translations', 'keywords.translations'])
        ->whereHas('usages.translations', function($query) use ($languageId) {
            $query->where('language_id', $languageId);
        })
        ->whereHas('keywords.translations', function($query) use ($languageId) {
            $query->where('language_id', $languageId);
        })
        ->get();
```

Comment: This unfortunately does not work - it fetches all language mutations.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need is a nested query as follows:

```
App\Paper::with(['usages.translations', 'keywords.translations'])
            ->where('usages.translations.language_id', 'your_id_goes_here')
            ->orWhere('keywords.translations.language_id', 'your_id_goes_here')
            ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it, however I am getting ```Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'usages.translation s.language_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `papers` where `usages`.`translations`.`language_id` = 1 or `keywords` .`translations`.`language_id` = 1)' ```